# Parsing non-zero padded timestamps in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get datetimes from timestamps like the following :`3/1/2014 9:55` with `datetime.strptime`, or something equivalent.

The month, day of month, and hour is not zero padded, but there doesn't seem to be a formatting directive listed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) that is able to parse this automatically.

What's the best approach to do so?  Thanks!

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`strptime` is able to parse non-padded values. The fact that they are noted as being padded in the formatting codes table applies to `strftime`'s output. So you can just use

```
datetime.strptime(datestr, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Answer (score 10):

`strptime` isdo not require 0-padded values. See example below

```
datetime.strptime("3/1/2014 9:55", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
output:   datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 1, 9, 55)
```

Answer (score 4):

The non-pattern way is use `dateutil.parse` module, it lets to parse the common date formats, even if you don't know what it is using currently

Ex:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> 
>>> utc_time     = '2014-08-13T00:00:00'
>>> verbose_time = '13-Aug-2014'
>>> some_locale  = '3/1/2014 9:55'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(utc_time)
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 13, 0, 0)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(verbose_time)
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 13, 0, 0)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(some_locale)
datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 1, 9, 55)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case this answer helps someone else -- I came here thinking I had a problem with zero padding, but it was actually to do with 12:00 vs 00:00 and the `%I` formatter.

The `%I` formatter is meant to match 12-hour-clock hours, optionally zero-padded.  But depending on your data source, you might get data that says that midnight or midday is actually zero, eg:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2015/01/01 0:12am', "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M%p")
ValueError: time data '2015/01/01 0:12am' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %I:%M'
```

What `strptime` actually wanted was a 12, not a zero:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('2015/01/01 12:12am', "%Y/%m/%d %I:%M%p")
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 12)
```

But we don't always control our data sources!  My solution for this edge case was to catch the exception, try parsing it with a `%H`, with a quick check that we are in the edge case we think we are in.

```
def get_datetime(string):
    try:
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(string, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")
    except ValueError:
        # someone used zero for midnight?
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(string, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M%p")
        assert string.lower().endswith('am')
        assert timestamp.hour == 0
    return timestamp
```

Comment: `0:12am` is invalid input. It should be `12:12am`. `11:59 pm` is followed by `12:00 am`, not `0:00am`. There could be variety of ways to supply data in a wrong time format e.g., input may use two-digit year (`%y`) instead of four-digit year (`%Y`) or day/month may be swapped (`%m/%d` vs. `%d/%m`), etc. The day/month case may be ambiguous e.g., `2015/10/12` is it "Oct 12" or "Dec 10"? btw, you should use `%Y/%m/%d` instead of `%m/%d/%Y` to match you input format.

Comment: Thanks, I do realise it's invalid input, as I say, it's coming from a data source which I don't control.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the strftime document [here](http://strftime.org/)，but in fact they aren't all working well in all platforms，for instance，`%-d，%-m` don't work on win7 by python 2.7，so you can accomplish like this

```
>>> date_str = '{d.year}-{d.month}-{d.day}'.format(d=datetime.datetime.now())  
>>> print(date_str)
2016-5-23
```

Comment: In native Windows, hash is substituted for dash: `%#d`, `%#m`. But both dash and hash mods are only needed in string formatting (`strftime`), not in parsing (`strptime`).