# Datetime pattern does not match in python even though bash recognizes it

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following code (based on http://strftime.org/):

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime("Apr 14, 2016 9", '%b %d, %Y %-I')
    print "matched date format"
except ValueError:
    print "did NOT match date format"
```

The above prints:

```
$ python parse_log.py
did NOT match date format
```

However bash recognizes this date format:

```
$ date  '+%b %d, %Y %-I'
Apr 14, 2016 1
```

What am I missing?

It seems that the %-I is the problem, since Python matches date without the %-I section:

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime("Apr 14, 2016 ", '%b %d, %Y ')
    print "matched date format"
except ValueError:
    print "did NOT match date format"
```

output:

```
$ python parse_log.py
matched date format
```

I'm on python 2.6.6.

The actual pattern I need to match uses 12 hour clock and is:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("Apr 14, 2016 9:59:54", '%b %d, %Y %-I:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `-` for [*strptime*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
 '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S'

In [17]: print  datetime.datetime.strptime("Apr 14, 2016 9:59:54", '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S')
2016-04-14 09:59:54
```

The `-I` is used only for [*strftime*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
In [15]: print datetime.datetime.strptime("Apr 14, 2016 9:59:54", '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S').strftime('%b %d, %Y %-I:%M:%S')
Apr 14, 2016 9:59:54
```

Comment: `-I` in bash is to parse non-zero padded values, but `strptime` will parse regardless of zero padding, as per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279993/parsing-non-zero-padded-timestamps-in-python