# Why does python's datetime.datetime.strptime('201412', '%Y%m%d') not raise a ValueError?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

In the format I am given, the date 2014-01-02 would be represented by "20140102".  This is correctly parsed with the standard strptime:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("20140102", "%Y%m%d")
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

In this format, "201412" would *not* be a valid date.  The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) say that the "%m" directive is "Month as a zero-padded decimal number."    It gives as examples "01, 02, ..., 12".  The days directive "%d" is also supposed to be  zero-padded.

Based on this, I expected that "201412" would be an invalid input with this format, so would raise a ValueError.  Instead, it is interpreted as 2014-01-02:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("201412", "%Y%m%d")
datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

The question is: is there a way to specify "no seriously zero-padded only"?  Or am I misunderstanding the term "zero-padded" in this context?

Note that the question is not about how to parse dates in this format, but about understanding the behavior of strptime.

Comment: This doesn't really help you, but it is somewhat related (think `/` separated fields) [Parsing non-zero padded timestamp in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279993/parsing-non-zero-padded-timestamps-in-python)

Comment: i think it depends on the regular expression the function uses

Comment: Looks like some additional explanation in the Python docs would be nice. Is it guaranteed, that `strptime("2014123", "%Y%m%d")` will always give `datetime(2014, 12, 3, 0, 0)` or could it be `datetime(2014, 1, 23, 0, 0)`?

Comment: Note that the documentation does **not** say that `%m` values must be zero-padded, it just says that it represents "month as a decimal number" and provides an example to show that it *can* be zero-padded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the related [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue22840) on the Python tracker, with the example being like such (a bit of a modification to this question, however the concept is the exact same):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('20141110', '%Y%m%d').isoformat()
'2014-11-10T00:00:00'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('20141110', '%Y%m%d%H%M').isoformat()
'2014-01-01T01:00:00'
```

The above behavior is determined to be **not** a bug as explained by [this comment](https://bugs.python.org/issue22840#msg230991) which states that they conform to the [OpenGroup strptime standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) which specifies that "leading zeros are permitted but not required.".

I guess the workaround is to use regex or check that the length of the string is of length 8 before passing into `strptime`.

Answer (score 6):

If you look here at how the regex is defined for `%m` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2d264235f6e066611b412f7c2e1603866e0f7f1b/Lib/_strptime.py#L204

`'m': r"(?P<m>1[0-2]|0[1-9]|[1-9])"`

You can see you can either have a 10-12, 01-09, or 1-9 as acceptable months.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty tricky, but it sounds like `strptime` just tries to match the string as closely as possible. Python's `strptime` is the same as C's `strptime`, and the docs say that padding is optional:

> is the month number [1,12]; leading zeros are permitted but not
>   required.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strptime.html