# Datetime Object without leading zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I've come across several answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525944/python-datetime-formatting-without-zero-padding/29980406), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279993/parsing-non-zero-padded-timestamps-in-python/25280059), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904928/python-strftime-date-without-leading-0)) regarding the **removal of leading zeros** on `python3`  `datetime` objects.

One of the most voted [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073189/797495) states:

> On Windows, you would use #, e.g. `%Y/%#m/%#d`

The code above doesn't work for me.  I've also tried the Linux solution, which uses `-` instead of `#`,  without success.

**Code**:

```
loop_date = "1950-1-1"
date_obj = datetime.strptime(loop_date, '%Y-%m-%d') # or '%Y-%#m-%#d' which produces the errors below
date_obj += timedelta(days=1)
print(date_obj)
# This the prints `1954-01-02` but I need `1954-1-2`
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/collect_games.py", line 84, in <module>
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(loop_date, '%Y-%-m-%d')
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\_strptime.py", line 354, in _strptime
    (bad_directive, format)) from None
ValueError: '#' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%#m#%d'
```

What's most *pythonic* approach to this problem?

Comment: you are parsing a time datetime here ... the `-` is applied when formatting an datetime into a string .... python does not need `02` inside a string to understands its the month or whatever ...  to parse the month from a string into a datetime object ?

Comment: remove the `-` between `%` and `m`.

Comment: I need the output to be formatted without the leading zero, which doesn't happen with my current code..

Comment: @Kasramvd  in php you  can use `j` for Day of the month without leading zeros or `d` for  Day of the month with leading zeros

Comment: You're creating a `datetime` object with a standard representation. Removing those zeros is another problem and related to the string representation of the object.

Comment: If you want to create a string representation from a datetime object without padding zeros you might want to use `strftime` method as is mentioned in @Patrick's answer.

Comment: The code on Patrick's answer, and the one on my question, runs fine on online compilers, but not on my windows python3.6 installation. I don't have a solution yet, but now I'm this is an installation problem rather than a syntax one.

Comment: @PedroLobito  - see edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing the formats of parsing (a string into a dt) and formatting (a dt into a string):

This works on **linux** (or online via http://pyfiddle.io):

```
import datetime 

dt = datetime.datetime.now()

# format datetime as string
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%-m-%-d'))  # - acts to remove 0 AND as delimiter

# parse a string into a datetime object
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("1022-4-09", '%Y-%m-%d')

print(dt2)
```

Output:

```
2018-4-5
1022-04-09 00:00:00
```

The `-` when formatting a string acts to remove the leading 0 AND as delimiter - for parsing it only needs to be placed as delimiter - parsing works on on either `02` or `2` for `%m`

---

This works on **Windows** (VS2017):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

loop_date = "1950-1-1"
date_obj = datetime.strptime(loop_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
date_obj += timedelta(days=1)
print(date_obj)   # output the datetime-object

print(datetime.strftime(date_obj,'%Y-%#m-%#d'))  # output it formatted
```

Output:

```
1950-01-02 00:00:00
1950-1-2
```

Comment: Your code produces : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/collect_games.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%-m-%d'))
ValueError: Invalid format string
` on `python 3.6` and there's nothing different from the question's code, which yields the same error.

Comment: @PedroLobito  copy my code into http://www.pyfiddle.io  - it works as 2.7 and 3.6 ?

Comment: Your code runs fine but not on my windows python3.6 . I'm almost sure this is an installation problem rather than a syntax one.

Comment: @PedroLobito  See edit. pyfiddle.io is a linux server

Comment: ***This works on Windows (VS2017)*** it does. Strange, because I've tried that...I guess I've to apply the "removal filter" (`-`) only at `print` time.  I'll mark your answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: @PedroLobito  RemoveAll - Filter would be `#` ;) for windows. Sorry for the confusion with linus syntax.

Comment: NP, all set, appreciated!