# Parse date format to datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I've come across a date format like this:

`8/17/18 19:00` which corresponds to August 17th, 2018.

I tried parsing this with:

1. `pendulum.parse(date)` --> returns all sorts of mixed dates when day is less than 12
2. `datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')`  --> `%m` goes 01 to 12, not this case

What is the correct way to parse this completely arbitrary date format ?

Comment: It's not arbitrary. Looks like an American military format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing non-zero padded timestamps in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279993/parsing-non-zero-padded-timestamps-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Match the number of digits in the year (`%y`), and include the hours and minutes (`%H:%M`).

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> date = '8/17/18 19:00'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 17, 19, 0)
```