# Problem using strptime when there is no 0 padding

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

```
today = datetime.strptime('Sep 3 2021 2:58 pm', '%b %d %Y %I:%M %p')
```

Returns the following error: time data `Sep 03 2021 2:58 pm` does not match format `%b %d %Y %I:%M %p`

Comment: works fine for me, which Python version are you using? Also, did you maybe set a specific [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html)?

Answer (score 0):

When I run it, it works fine. Perhaps you can try the following:

```
today = datetime.strptime('Sep 3 2021 2:58 pm', '%b %-d %Y %I:%M %p')
```

`%-d` should be used if the day number is not zero-padded (i.e. Sep 3 instead of Sep 03). According to [this website](https://strftime.org/) this is platform-specific, so perhaps you are using a platform that requires you to specify it is not zero-padded.

Comment: I'm using windows. I've tried adding "-", however it just returns that it is a bad directive for the format. I'm on Python 3.9.7 according to anaconda

Comment: Apparently, padding is only an issue with strftime, not strptime according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279993/parsing-non-zero-padded-timestamps-in-python/25280059, not sure why it doesn't work for you, sorry!

Comment: Well, I restarted the kernel and it worked. No idea why. Thank you very much sir. Wouldn't have tried this if t wasn't for what you said!

Comment: Great to hear, good luck!